# Join two tables to get common data based on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

- `Table1` with columns `colA, colB, colC`
- `Table2` with columns `colX, colY, colZ`

I'm trying to get all rows from `Table1` which have `colC` values that match  `Table2` on `colZ`.

I tried the following:

```
select Table1.colA,Table1.colB,Table1.colC 
from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.colC = Table2.colZ
```

This does not seem to work as the result of the query had 20 times the number of rows present in `Table1`.

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) like this.

```
select Table1.colA,Table1.colB,Table1.colC from Table1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.colC = Table2.colZ)
```

Comment: What does select 1 mean in this case ??

Comment: In an `EXISTS` query we only need to check if the correlated sub query has a matching record, hence the `SELECT 1` doesn't denote anything special. you can even use `SELECT *`

Answer (score 4):

Three options:

1. Use `INNER JOIN` with `DISTINCT`

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT Table1.colA,
                   Table1.colB,
                   Table1.colC 
              FROM Table1 
        INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.colC = Table2.colZ
   ```
2. Use `EXISTS`

   ```
   SELECT Table1.colA,
          Table1.colB,
          Table1.colC 
     FROM Table1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE ColZ = ColC)
   ```
3. Use `IN`

   ```
   SELECT Table1.colA,
          Table1.colB,
          Table1.colC 
     FROM Table1 
    WHERE ColC IN (SELECT ColZ FROM Table2)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` in your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Table1.colA,Table1.colB,Table1.colC 
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 
  ON Table1.colC = Table2.colZ
```